# jQuery KeyUp and mouse Click couldn't work same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

**Button Click search prefect Working  Only Error For Search By Enter Key**

> **Only For NoRecord Result Otherwise Working Correctly**

if i search No record result it working once again even  i try to correct record does not work hide the popup form &  submitted successful mgs display.

**This Is the Enter Key Function**

```js
$("#app-search").keyup(function (event) {
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
$(".search-pool").click();    
}    
});
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 pull-right" id="search-view">
<div class="input-group">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.search, new { id = "app-search", @class = "form-control"})
<a id="btn-clear-search2" class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></a>
 <span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="search-pool btn btn-primary" type="button">
<span class="fa fa-search"></span>
</button>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**This is the Button Click Function**

```js
$('.search-pool').on('click', function () {
$('#label-error').hide();
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("PoolDetails")',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'html',
data: { search: $('#app-search').val() }
})
.done(function (responce) {
$('#pool-details').html(responce);
$('#btn-clear-search2').show();
checkSelected();
 FillSelected();
})
});
```

[image]

Comment: Try putting `$(".search-pool").trigger('click');` inside `keyup()` event.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto No its working the same

Comment: Is that `event.keyCode` returns undefined? Probably you should try `event.which` instead.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto No brother It will working but when i search NoData Only dont Work